# Keyboard showing in Telegram Web View IOS overlaps input/textarea

Tags: html, css, webview, telegram, telegram-bot

Keyboard overlaps on the input/textarea located in the bottom[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L0ucn.jpg)

```
.chat {
  // display: flex;
  // flex-flow: column;
  // justify-content: space-between;
  // align-items: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: black;

  textarea {
    position: absolute;
    left: 15px;
    bottom: 15px;
    // margin-top: 550px;
    // margin-left: 15px;
    width: calc(100% - 30px);
    height: 100px;
    padding: 6px 50px 6px 6px;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 8px;
    background-color: rgb(35, 35, 35);
    outline: none;
    font-size: 20px;
    resize: none;
    z-index: 1;
  }
}
```

Telegram: 9.3.2
IOS: 16.1.2

I have tried a lot of approaches: different position types, display flex, interactive widget=resizes-content, and somehow getting the height of the keyboard/visible view. Unfortunately, all of these approaches were unsuccessful.

It's need to be:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tQoGP.jpg)

Comment: Weird bug. Affects my bot too.